# integrate over $d[x]$

Tags: calculus, integration, number-theory

I was looking at the following: https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/mertens.pdf

How is the integral $\int f dg$ defined if $g$ isn't differentiable? In this case $g(x)=[x]$ (I understand in this case the equalitys in the link and the meaning of the integral.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you looking for is called [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are both functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Then one can try to define
$$ \int_a^b f \; dg := \lim \sum_{x_i} f(x_i) \Big( g(x_{i+1}) - g(x_i)\Big),$$
where the $x_i$ partition $[a,b]$, and where the limit is taken as the mesh of the partition gets finer. This is to be interpreted similarly to the definition of the usual Riemann integral, except with the addition of the function $g$.

This is called the **Riemann-Stieltjes integral**. It does not always exist (just as with the Riemann integral). But it is very useful, and it is very useful in classical analytic number theory. In the context of analytic number theory, what some people call "summation by parts" or "partial summation" can be interpreted as integration by parts in the Riemann-Stieltjes sense. Euler-Maclaurin summation is repeated integration by parts with a clever choice of antiderivatives along the way.